# Cant add an element to array

Tags: c++, массивы

I wanted to add an array name as last element of the array, but i got an error: **CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.**

```
#include <iostream>

int SizeOfSet();
void AddName(int* &arr, int size, const char name);
void Initialize(int* arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int size = SizeOfSet();

    int *A = new int(size);
    Initialize(A, size);
    AddName(A, size, 'A');

    return 0;
}

int SizeOfSet()
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "Enter an amout of set:\n";
    std::cin >> size;

    return size;
}

void Initialize(int* arr, int size)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         std::cout << "Enter a number:" << std::endl;
         std::cin >> arr[i];
     }
}

void AddName(int* &arr, int size, const char name)
{
    int* newArr = new int[size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    { 
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;

    newArr[size] = static_cast<int>(name);

    arr = newArr;
}
```

Comment: переведите вопрос на русский язык и объясните что у вас не вышло. Суда по коду он делает полную чушь, а что вы хотели взамен?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу пишу код, который должен создавать 2 множества, а потом выполнять над ними операции. Я хочу добавить имя множество такое как "A" и "B" в виде кода в конец самих множеств, чтобы потом пользователь мог написать имена этих множеств для проведения операций, к примеру: A + B, B - A, !A и так далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может быть

```
int* newArr = new int[size + 1];
```

?

ну и судя по коду

```
void AddName(int* &arr, int size, const char name){
```

Comment: Уже пробовал, все равно не работает

Comment: `void AddName(int* arr, int size, const char name){` - надо указатель по ссылке передавать раз вы `arr = newArr` делаете

Comment: **CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer**